# Type of sort in Backbone JS (on the fly)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to sort my table of users when I click on a th. 
My users have :

- a first name
- a last name
- an age
- an id

When I click on a th, a sort happen but :

- When I sort my users by first or last name, it works only on asc direction.
- When I sort my users by age, it works, both direction

Any idea ?

Here is my view :

```
var UserListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: ".page",
  events: {
    'click .delete': 'deleteUser',
    'click th': 'sortItem',
  },
  initialize: function(){
    this.users = new UsersCollection();

  },

  sortItem: function(ev) {
    var that = this;  
    var field = ev.currentTarget.id;
    this.users.sort_field(field);
    this.render();
  },

  deleteUser: function(ev) {
    var id = ev.currentTarget.dataset.userId;
    var user = new UserModel({
      id: id
    });
    user.destroy({
      success: function() {
        var userList = new UserListView();
        userList.render();
      }
    })
  },

  render: function() {
    var that = this;      
    this.users.fetch({
      success: function(users) {
        var template = _.template(UserListTemplate, {
          users: users.models
        });
        that.$el.html(template);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

And my collection :

```
var UsersCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: UserModel,
  url: "/users",
  initialize: function() {
    this._compar = 'id';
    this._sortDir = 'asc';
  },
  comparator: function(user) {
    console.log(this._sortDir);
    return this._sortDir == 'asc' ? user.get(this._compar) : -user.get(this._compar);
  },

  sort_field: function(field) {
    this._compar = field;
    this._sortDir = this._sortDir == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
    this.sort();
  }

});
```

Comment: Is the `id` numeric and should be sorted as a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You can't reverse the sort order of strings by negating them.
2. Your sort direction flips every time `sort_field` is called even when you're changing the field, presumably changing the field should reset the direction to ascending.

First things first. If you switch to a two argument `comparator` then you can easily fix **(1)** by comparing things with `<` and `>` rather than trying to use the *negation to reverse the order* trick:

```
comparator: function(a, b) {
    a = a.get(this._compar);
    b = b.get(this._compar);
    var els = this._sortDir == 'asc' ? [ a, b ] : [ b, a ];
    return els[0]  > els[1] ?  1
         : els[0]  < els[1] ? -1
         :                     0;
}
```

There are lots of ways to write that logic but there all just variations on the above theme.

You can fix **(2)** simply by checking if the `field` is changing, if it is then reset the sort direction, if it isn't then just flip the direction:

```
sort_field: function(field) {
    if(this._compar == field) {
        this._sortDir = this._sortDir == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
    }
    else {
        this._compar  = field;
        this._sortDir = 'asc';
    }
    this.sort();
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Br4Kj/

Separating the sort field and sort direction at the view level might make more sense though, then you could have separate field (`collection.sort_field(field)`) and direction (`collection.sort_dir(dir)`) calls; calling `sort_field` would, of course, reset the direction to ascending and `sort_dir` would leave the sort field alone.

Comment: you're my hero :)

I have another (tiny) question : how backbone.js deals with that part : els[0]  > els[1] 

For exemple, I have "aaaa","AAAA" and "1111", how does it know which type of sort it has to do ? I'm just curious to know how it works, cause I didn't find any documentation about it.

Comment: @Kai23: Backbone doesn't do anything with that, that's just JavaScript comparing strings and numbers with the same `<` and `>` operators.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification ! Have a good night (or day, don't know which part of the planet you are ;) )